# Trigger change data before insert/update happens, then continue

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to change data before an insert/update happens, the following will describe what I'm trying to accomplish, I just don't know how.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [my trigger]
ON [dbo].[my table] 
INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE 
AS
BEGIN;
    IF(  **value of column [x] = "a"**  )
        **change value of column [y] to "b"**

    **continue insert or update**
END;
```

I know that the pseudo table `inserted` is available, but I don't know how to handle the different triggers (being either an insert or an update).

How should I continue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your trigger `AFTER INSERT/UPDATE` instead of `INSTEAD OF`, so you just need to update the value afterwards and don't need to redo the original insert or update operation.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [my trigger] ON [dbo].[my table] 
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
AS
BEGIN

    IF UPDATE(Columnx)
    BEGIN

        UPDATE T SET
            ColumnY = 'New Value'
        FROM
            [dbo].[my table] AS T
            INNER JOIN inserted AS I ON T.KeyColumn = I.KeyColumn
        WHERE
            I.ColumnX = 'Value To Check'

    END

END
```

Comment: Ok that was my first thought as well, but doesn't this create unnecessary load because the trigger has to check the whole table every time?

Comment: @Aquillo not if you join against `inserted` and your table is properly indexed.

Comment: You're absolutely right, thank you! Will accept as soon as I can (have to wait a few minutes)...